# Post Job Offers through the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-ads-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to post job offers through the FB API? I am asking in context of this article https://facebook.com/business/news/take-the-work-out-of-hiring

I searched for something in the FB documentation, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?  I am wondering the same thing

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-api/getting-started

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya that link doesn't work.

Comment: might be they remove that page @AndrewChristensen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been exploring the same thing, and minus an official FB statement that they do not support this through Graph API or otherwise, I'd safely say that it is not currently possible/supported.

Comment: it is a closed beta

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Facebook is rolling this out now. It might not be available to you just yet (I can't use it in the UK).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml

https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/02/jobs/