# Which facebook marketing API to call to post free job ads on facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Facebook has a feature to create job ads on 
https://www.facebook.com/jobs/?init_composer=0
This job ad is associated with employers page and posted without charge. How to do this via API? Which facebook marketing API to call to post free job ads on facebook page?

Comment: Don't think there is an API. But you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs to see if you can find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post Job Offers through the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714204/post-job-offers-through-the-facebook-api)