# How to post job on social media platform?

Tags: java, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I have an application from which a user need post job onto social media platform like Facebook,twitter,but my main concern is Facebook.

I have already gone through:
1)Spring social Facebook
2)Facebook Graph API
and also this
[Post Job Offers through the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714204/post-job-offers-through-the-facebook-api)

But failed to find out the concrete steps to post as most of the example shows ony how to perform "GET"

I have all the data which I need to post for example message,link,image etc.

So is there any class which can post all the data as post through Spring social Facebook?
or 
do I have to create the an XML as shown in Facebook Graph API?is there any example?
(I have already searched and found none besides the one in documentation)

Thanks you:)

Comment: Attempt to solve the problem, then come back with code examples and any errors (with stacktraces) that you encounter.

Comment: @cameron1024 I will post the code which I have tried:)

Comment: _“or do I have to create the an XML as shown in Facebook Graph API?”_ - yes. That is currently the only way, there is no API endpoint that you could actively post your job data to directly. _“is there any example? (I have already searched and found none besides the one in documentation)”_ - and? Why would you need two different examples for the same thing in the first place? You can see the necessary structure there, required fields/elements are listed above … so what more do you need?

Comment: @misorude so I dump the idea of using facebook graph API as I need to contact facebook for Job API persmission for my app,now i am using restFb,but whatever I do its allowing me to post to a page only?why I cant post to timeline feed anymore?

Comment: _“why I cant post to timeline feed anymore?”_ - because that got abused way too much by shady apps to create spam posts, so Facebook removed it.